# Modify a specific attribute via an Array containing references

Tags: javascript, attributes

How could I make the following more efficient?:

```
var varToChange = ['playerList',24,'hp',24];

//Sending that info to the client...

if(varToChange.length == 2){
 window[varToChange[0]] = varToChange[1]
}
...
if(varToChange.length == 4){
 window[varToChange[0]][varToChange[1]][varToChange[2]][varToChange[3]] = varToChange[4]
}
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript? Please add this tag.

Comment: Yes. It's javascript.

Comment: Are you supposed to be skipping over `varToChange[3]`?

Comment: No, my bad. But the concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tmp = window;
var length = varToChange.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length - 2; i++) {
    tmp = tmp[varToChange[i]];
}
tmp[varToChange[length - 2]] = varToChange[length - 1];
```

Note that the fact that you're doing this looks like a warning sign to me. There's probably a better way to implement whatever you're doing.

Comment: Working fine. :D But yeah, the way I'm oing this is probably not 'proper' coding. Still, it may become handy.